# Calculating distance between adresses using Google API in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-maps-api-3

I found code online to calculate the distance between several addresses (~10k pairs). Two different codes from two websites both give me an error.

I created my own Google API, and activated billing (using the URL test works for me) and tried some suggestions from other forums.

**1. Approach**
Found on: https://analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/

```vb
'Calculate Google Maps distance between two addresses
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

Every time I apply the formula, I get a "-1" i.e. error message.

**2. Approach**
Found on: https://syntaxbytetutorials.com/excel-function-to-calculate-distance-using-google-maps-api-with-vba/

I added VBA-JSON and activated references as suggested by the author.

```vb
' Returns the number of seconds it would take to get from one place to another
Function TRAVELDISTANCE(origin, destination, apikey)
 
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" &amp; origin &amp; "&amp;destination=" &amp; destination &amp; "&amp;key=" &amp; apikey
     
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send
    End With
     
    Dim response As String
    response = httpReq.ResponseText
     
    Dim parsed As Dictionary
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim meters As Integer
     
    Dim leg As Dictionary
    
    For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
        meters = meters + leg("distance")("value")
    Next leg
     
    TRAVELDISTANCE = meters
 
End Function
```

The function does not compile due to an error in the line

```vb
strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" &amp; origin &amp; "&amp;destination=" &amp; destination &amp; "&amp;key=" &amp; apikey
```

It returns an error.

> Expected: end of statement

Comment: In the second approach you're clearly building the URL in the wrong way. When you're concatenating strings, there needs to be a `&` between two strings and if a string is not stored in a variable then it should be in quotes.

Comment: Just doing a quick read on how the API is supposed to be formatted for the distance matrix, are the start and dest strings being properly formatted?  Also, have you  run any manual test cases to ensure that you're getting the URL built correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your answers Stravos Jon and Chaosbydesign. Indeed, made an error in the formatting of the address after reviewed the required design of the strings needed for the API. After correcting the issue, the 1st formula worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the second approach is concerned, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start), the URL should look like the following example:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=YOUR_API_KEY

So in your case, if you have a variable named `origin`, another one named `destination` and a third one named `apikey`, the URL should be built like so:

```
strUrl ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
```

The function would have to be called like so, for example:

```
call TRAVELDISTANCE("Disneyland", "Universal+Studios+Hollywood", "xxxxx")
```

I suppose what happened is that in the website where you found the original code, the `&` character was resolved in its HTML version which is: `&amp;`. This however will give an error in VBA.

So before copying and pasting something you need to understand how it works.

To combine strings the following applies in general:

```
finalString= String1 & String2 & "String3" & "String4" & ..... 'depending on whether your strings are stored in variables or not.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Replacing the &amp; with & actually helped to make the code running.